# Fixed footer with 960.gs

Tags: css, sticky-footer, 960.gs

I want to create fixed footer but , is it possible with 960 gs , because I am having trouble with height of container div . I can no set it to %100.

```
<div class="container_12" > 
    <div class="grid_3" id="side-space"></div>
    <div class="grid_6">
         <div id="content-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3" id="side-space"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe 960.gs has much to do with height.. it just deals with columns and clearing. Nice framework to start with. Try setting body to 100% and then setting `#content-box` to 100%.  Here is a random example I came across

```
<!-- IE in quirks mode -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<title>Fixed footer</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0;
padding:0 0 <length> 0;
}
div#footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:<length>;
}
@media screen{
body>div#footer{
position: fixed;
}
}
* html body{
overflow:hidden;
} 
* html div#content{
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
</style>
<div id="footer"> footer </div>
<div id="content"> content </div>
```